# Why doesn't json.loads('{"Testing": "This quo\\\\"te String"}')) work?

Tags: python, json, string, escaping

I'm trying to understand why the code below doesn't work in Python:

```
import json

s = json.loads(' {"Testing" : "This quo\\\\"te String"} ')

print(s)
```

Theoretically, what I should get back is `{'Testing' : 'This quo\"te String'}`.

These ones work fine:

```
print(json.loads(' {"Testing" : "This quo\\"te String"} ')) ----> {'Testing' : 'This quo"te String'}

print(json.loads(' {"Testing" :"This quo\\\\\\"te String"}')) ----> {'Testing' : 'This quo\\"te String'}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the Idiosyncrasy of having a `\"` in the dict, but can't figure out what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `This quo\"te String` requires two escapes in normal Python: one for the `\` and one for the `"`, making three backslashes in all:

```
>>> print("This quo\\\"te String")
This quo\"te String
```

For json, all those backslashes must be themselves escaped, because the string is embedded inside another string. Thus, six backslashes are required in total:

```
>>> print(json.loads('"This quo\\\\\\"te String"'))
This quo\"te String
```

However, if *raw-strings* are used, no extra escapes are required:

```
>>> print(json.loads(r'"This quo\\\"te String"'))
This quo\"te String
```

In your first example, the four backslashes will be parsed as a single literal `\` (i.e. as an escaped backslash), leaving the `"` unescaped.

Note that it makes no difference if the string is inside a `dict` - the result will be exactly the same:

```
>>> dct = json.loads('{"Testing": "This quo\\\\\\"te String"}')
>>> print(dct['Testing'])
This quo\"te String
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ekhumoro. I'm still a bit confused though since in my question I was mainly looking at how to get the python dict {'Testing' : 'This quo\"te String'} back from that JSON string. My thinking was that in JSON string having \\" results in just an escaped double quote; having \\\\" results in \" and having \\\\\\" results in \\" but the  \\\\" variant isn't successful in returning a python dict.

Comment: While your specific example works, when I do print(json.loads('{"Testing": "This quo\\\\\\"te String"} ')) it returns {'Testing' : 'This quo\\"te String'} and not {'Testing' : 'This quo\"te String'}

Comment: @ManDem It makes no difference whether it's inside a dict or not, the results are *exactly the same*. When you print a dict object, you always get the `repr` of it's contents - so the escaping will remain. To see the literal output, you must print the value itself: `d = json.loads('{"Testing": "This quo\\\\\\"te String"}'); print(d['Testing'])` => `This quo\"te String`.

Comment: @ManDem As explained in my answer, the problem isn't with the backslashes: it's with the embedded double-quote. Your first example ***does not escape it all***, so json cannot parse it properly.

Comment: Ah, I see. This was the missing link. One last question. Would it ever be possible to get a print of a dict object where there is only 1 backslash? I. e, {'Testing' : 'This quo\"te String'}

Comment: I know I said the previous question was the last question, but this is the last question. I promise. Why does the repr of contents keep some of the escapes but not the others? Basically, why does it return `{'Testing': 'This quo\\"te String'}` for `print(json.loads(' {"Testing" :"This quo\\\\\\"te String"}'))` instead of `{'Testing': 'This quo\\\"te String'}`.

Comment: @ManDem (1) No. Basically, python applies `repr` to all of the elements of containers such as dict, list, etc. This avoids problems with ambiguous cases like `1` (int) / `"1"` (str) which display the same when printed. Using `repr` preserves vital information about the type of the contained elements. (2) A single-quoted string doesn't need to escape embedded double-quotes (and *vice versa*).

Comment: I understand now. It's these little things, like the double quote changing to single quote that catch me out. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

You need an odd number of *pairs of backslashes* in your python string to end up with an odd number of *backslashes* in the json. Each pair of backslashes then becomes a single backslash and you need one more -- the odd one -- to escape the quote mark.

Comment: But what if I wanted to get a dict return from a JSON string specifically for  {'Testing' : 'This quo\"te String'}